# jasper server manual installation on weblogic

Tags: installation, weblogic12c

I'm trying to install jasper on Weblogic. My database is Oracle. When I try to run `js-ant create-js-db`, its giving me error invoking `getDriver()`. I copied **ojdc.jar** to **conf_source\db\oracle\jdbc** folder.
Following is the error:

```
create-js-db:
     [echo] About to validate JDBC jar existence
     [echo]   Look in: C:/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-bin/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-bin/buildomatic/conf_source/db/oracle/jdbc
     [echo]   Found jar file: assuming OK
     [echo]   Jar or Jars found: ojdbc6.jar
BUILD FAILED
C:\jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-bin\jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-bin\buildomatic\conf_source\db\oracle\db.xml:40: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-bin\jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-bin\buildomatic\bin\app-server.xml:60: C:\jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-bin\jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-bin\buildomatic\bin\app-ser
ver.xml:60: Error invoking getDriver() method
```

Could anyone let me know what is wrong?

Comment: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/844083/jasperserver-oracle-jdbc-error-no-suitable-driver

Comment: Is the link you posted the answer? If it worked for you, please post your solution as an answer so everyone knows this question was resolved

Comment: yes, the above link resolved problem